# DynamoDbMapper.S3Link equivalent code in aws-java-sdk-2

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk, aws-sdk-java-2.0

I am working on migrating some DynamoDB code from version 1 of the AWS Java SDK to version 2 of the SDK. I have been unable to find an equivalent code for the `DynamoDbMapper.S3Link` in version 2 of the SDK. Does anyone know whether this ability was dropped? or do we need to do this via the S3 SDK now?

I have a few Pojos that look something like the following, so I am trying to figure out how to migrate these

```
class Pojo{
  private S3Link link
}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That functionality is not yet possible using SDK V2 unfortunately. You will have to make the call to S3 first using the S3 client, then store the metadata on DynamoDB.

Comment: Thanks Leeroy! Are there any plans to add this support, or is this the new way?

Comment: I've not heard of plans, but the best way to find out is on their GitHub: https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java-v2/tree/master/services-custom/dynamodb-enhanced